# MS Access: Count Number of Fields Per Record That Contain Specific Value And Use This Count As Default Value of Another Field Within The Same Record

Tags: sql, ms-access, if-statement, ms-access-2016, iif

Users import the serial number, then they are to fill the data for Error Name. Each serial number can have a maximum of 3 Error Names. The Error Names are then classified as either Type A or Type B.

Then there is the SumOfErrorTypeA field and SumOfErrorTypeB field. Users manually type in the Sum of each error type per record but our team needs to automate it. I tried IIFs, Dcounts, VBA math, to no avail... Is there a way to do it? Thank you!

```
Record SerialNumber Error1Name Error1Type Error2Name Error2Type Error3Name Error3Type SumOfErrorTypeA SumOfErrorTypeB
1      111111111    Error1     Type B     Error2     Type A     Error3     Type A     2               1
2      222222222    Error1     Type A     Error2     Type A                           2               0
3      333333333    Error1     Type A                                                 1               0
4      444444444    No error                                                          0               0
```

I tried IIFs, DCounts, VBA, nothing worked.

Comment: This data is clearly not normalized. Is there a normalized variant of this data available?

Comment: Hi @Erik von Asmuth. thank you for replying... I am a newbie and had to google what normalized data is! i learned something new! thank you! It's been answered but thank you for noticing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the sums:

```
select t.*,
       (iif(Error1Type = "A", 1, 0) +
        iif(Error2Type = "A", 1, 0) +
        iif(Error3Type = "A", 1, 0)
       ) as num_a,
       (iif(Error1Type = "B", 1, 0) +
        iif(Error2Type = "B", 1, 0) +
        iif(Error3Type = "B", 1, 0)
       ) as num_b
from t;
```

I'm not sure what you want to do with values, but this let's you calculate what they should be.